# How to predict a textual field on the basis of input features

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, regression

I'm stuck with a problem statement of predicting an identifier for a product on the basis of couple of product features. A sample of data available to me looks like the one shown below:

```
ABC10L 20.0 34 XYZ G345F FG MKD -> 000000DEF_VYA
```

Here, ABC10L,20.0,34,XYZ,G345F,FG,MKD are the features and 000000DEF_VYA is the unique identifier associated with the product. Initially I tried to formulate this problem as a regression problem but I'm not sure how to generate textual output from my model and what should be my cost function. Also, I'm not sure is regression the right tool to solve the issue here.

Please help in suggesting the right approach and how I may proceed to solve this !!!

Comment: Why regression and not classification? How many possible values for the target variable (identifier) are there?

Comment: hi @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87, thanks for reply. Actually target variable as the name suggest is a unique identifier for a product or a set of product. Also, if it is same for a set of product it is not guaranteed that they relate to each other. Therefore, in worst case scenario it'll be equal to N where N is number of data points or records.

Comment: I first thought of using regression as in contrast to house cost prediction problem where we take in features of house and try to predict house price of unseen house using it's features. But here i'm unable to think how to use regression.

Comment: Also, one proposed NLP solution might look like combining all the feature fields to generate one big string and generate identifier using that combined text. Does any NLP technique/model relate around this idea. Please help !!!

Comment: Your problem definition seems a bit vague. Do you know anything of the relation between features and target?

Comment: The problem statement is to generate target identifier given attributes of a product. Actually how this was done previously in legacy system was we had the product features similar to above mentioned in question, the system used to combine those features to generate a big string and apply some rule/function over that big string to get the final product label or identifier that governs further processing.

Comment: Now when re-designing the system we're trying to implement some ML algorithm to replicate this process of identifier generation where now we're trying to predict the identifier to as close as possible to what was generated by the legacy system which was using rule based approach.

Comment: So, either we can use raw features here to derive the final identifier or might can combine the data and use that as single input to model. we have tried to formulate this as ML problem but no luck as of now. Do you think it can be solved using ML ?

Comment: Now I understand better. If you have your rules to generate IDs, there is no need to use Machine Learning (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/when-to-use-machine-learning.html).